# Parameter passing to ZK portlet from straight java portlet

Tags: java, redirect, parameters, zk

All of our ZK portlets are written with straight java, not using ZUL pages, so please respond in these terms, and not in a straight normal ZK portlet. ie, our zul file only contains

And the Show class extends Window, and redirects to a java class that builds pages with a Java implementation of ZK.

The problem is, all our portlets are in seperate WAR files, so using a session parameter to pass objects around does not work. In an attempt to get around this, URL parameters are being use, but the problem is using the following code:

```
String name = Executions.getCurrent().getParameter("name");
log.info("parameter name:<" + name + ">" );
String requestpath = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getRequestPath();
log.info("parameter requestpath:<" + requestpath + ">" );
```

returns:

11 Nov 2013 17:11:48,432 INFO [Page:103] parameter dupeorgname: 11 Nov 2013 17:11:48,433 INFO [Page:105] parameter requestpath:

I have tried this in the Show.java class, as well as subsequent classes, and this parameter is missing.

Passing the parameter works, as that code and output look like:

redirect += "?name=" + name; log.info("redirect URL: " + redirect ); actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect);

Nov 2013 17:11:47,452 INFO [CreateOrganization:111] redirect URL: http://{URLHERE}/dupeOrg?name=parker

(URLHERE is filled out properly, just hiding)

Anyone have a process for passing parameters to a ZK portlet written with straight java and not using ZUL files?

Comment: Inter portlet communication should be agnostic to the "way of work", if you're using liferay check the [following](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/73250/inter-portlet-communication-on-liferay/)

Comment: Not sure how that is helpful...